# How to avoid printing the curl command on Jenkins Console Output?

Tags: curl, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am using Jenkins Declarative pipeline like :

```
...
stage('xxx'){
  steps{
    script{
      withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'Openshift_Credentials', passwordVariable: 'OPENSHIFT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'OPENSHIFT_USERNAME')]) {
        def encoded = "${OPENSHIFT_USERNAME}:${OPENSHIFT_PASSWORD}".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()

        def data = sh returnStdout: true, script: "curl -k --form version=${XXX} --form env=${XXX} --form app=${XXX} -H \"Authorization: Basic ${encoded}\" \"SOME_API\""

        print data

}
...
```

Now, it is working fine, but I am seeing the curl command mentioned in script on Jenkins console output :

```
[Pipeline] sh
14:13:04  + curl -k --form version=VALUE   --form env=VALUE   --form app=VALUE   -H Authorization: Basic ENCODED_VALUE SOME_API
14:13:04    % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
14:13:04                                   Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
14:13:08  
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   340    0     0  100   340      0    250  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   251
```

Is there a way we can avoid printing that curl command on console? (I don't want to show that encoded value on console)

I know that set +x can be used in Shell Script for this, but I don't want to use sh ''' block

How can I do in my example?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196549/hide-curl-output) to enable silent or quiet mode :

Comment: When you convert your credentials environment variable to a Groovy variable and assign it to the variable `encoded`, you basically prevent the capability to redact your sensitive output. You would need to use the credentials as an environment variable from `withCredentials` instead.